# Can I map capslock to lshift + rshift?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I want to toggle `capslock` when I hit both `shift` keys at once. Is this possible?

I'm currently using `xubuntu` and `xmodmap` if it matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/default/keyboard :
XKBOPTIONS="shift:both_capslock"

if you have other options, separate them with comma within the double quotes.